# I want to update a debian package, but apt deletes packages that are needed

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, aptitude

I can see that my xfce4-panel version didn't get upgraded to 4.16 (it's still 4.12) after upgrading debian from buster to bullseye. So I wrote `sudo apt install xfce4-panel` to try to upgrade xfce4-panel. But then I'm greeted with this suggestion to remove the packages that I am using, like clang, libreoffice and so on

```
$ sudo apt install xfce4-panel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ant ant-optional asymptote asymptote-doc coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1v5 coinor-libcoinutils3v5
  coinor-libosi1v5 cpp-8 dh-python firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc firebird3.0-server-core firebird3.0-utils freeglut3
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 ibverbs-providers lib32asan5 lib32atomic1 lib32gcc-8-dev lib32gcc1 lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32mpx2 lib32quadmath0
  lib32stdc++6 lib32ubsan1 libabw-0.1-1 libactivation-java libaopalliance-java libapache-poi-java libapache-pom-java libargs4j-java libasan5
  libasm-java libatinject-jsr330-api-java libbase-java libbcmail-java libbcpkix-java libbcprov-java libboost-atomic-dev
  libboost-atomic1.67-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-chrono1.67-dev libboost-container-dev libboost-container1.67-dev
  libboost-container1.67.0 libboost-context-dev libboost-context1.67-dev libboost-context1.67.0 libboost-coroutine-dev
  libboost-coroutine1.67-dev libboost-coroutine1.67.0 libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.67-dev libboost-dev libboost-exception-dev
  libboost-exception1.67-dev libboost-fiber-dev libboost-fiber1.67-dev libboost-fiber1.67.0 libboost-filesystem-dev
  libboost-filesystem1.67-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.67-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.67.0
  libboost-graph1.67-dev libboost-graph1.67.0 libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.67-dev libboost-locale-dev libboost-locale1.67-dev
  libboost-log-dev libboost-log1.67-dev libboost-log1.67.0 libboost-math-dev libboost-math1.67-dev libboost-math1.67.0 libboost-mpi-dev
  libboost-mpi1.67-dev libboost-mpi1.67.0 libboost-numpy-dev libboost-numpy1.67-dev libboost-numpy1.67.0 libboost-program-options-dev
  libboost-program-options1.67-dev libboost-program-options1.67.0 libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.67-dev libboost-python1.67.0
  libboost-random-dev libboost-random1.67-dev libboost-random1.67.0 libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.67-dev libboost-regex1.67.0
  libboost-serialization-dev libboost-serialization1.67-dev libboost-serialization1.67.0 libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.67-dev
  libboost-signals1.67.0 libboost-stacktrace-dev libboost-stacktrace1.67-dev libboost-stacktrace1.67.0 libboost-system-dev
  libboost-system1.67-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.67-dev libboost-test1.67.0 libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.67-dev
  libboost-timer-dev libboost-timer1.67-dev libboost-timer1.67.0 libboost-tools-dev libboost-type-erasure-dev libboost-type-erasure1.67-dev
  libboost-type-erasure1.67.0 libboost-wave-dev libboost-wave1.67-dev libboost-wave1.67.0 libboost1.67-dev libboost1.67-tools-dev
  libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libc6-i386 libc6-x32 libcaf-openmpi-3 libcdi-api-java libcglib-java libclang-common-7-dev libclang1-7
  libcoarrays-openmpi-dev libcodec2-0.8.1 libcodec2-0.8.1:i386 libcodemodel-java libcommons-cli-java libcommons-codec-java
  libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-collections4-java libcommons-compress-java libcommons-io-java libcommons-lang3-java
  libcommons-logging-java libcommons-math3-java libcommons-parent-java libcrystalhd3 libcrystalhd3:i386 libcurvesapi-java libdc1394-22
  libdom4j-java libdouble-conversion1 libdtd-parser-java libe-book-0.1-1 libehcache-java libel-api-java libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1
  libevent-core-2.1-6 libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libfabric1 libfastinfoset-java libfbclient2 libfluidsynth1 libflute-java libfonts-java
  libformula-java libfreehand-0.1-1 libgeronimo-annotation-1.3-spec-java libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java libguava-java libguice-java
  libhawtjni-runtime-java libhsqldb1.8.0-java libhttpclient-java libhttpcore-java libhwloc-dev libhwloc-plugins libhwloc15 libhwloc5
  libib-util libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libicu4j-java libintellij-annotations-java libisl19 libistack-commons-java libitext-java
  libjansi-java libjansi-native-java libjaxb-api-java libjaxb-java libjaxen-java libjcommon-java libjdom1-java libjetbrains-annotations-java
  libjs-jquery-ui libjsoup-java libjsp-api-java libjsr305-java liblayout-java libloader-java liblog4j1.2-java libmail-java
  libmaven-file-management-java libmaven-parent-java libmaven-resolver-java libmaven-shared-io-java libmaven-shared-utils-java
  libmaven3-core-java libmpdec2 libmpx2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmypaint-1.3-0 libmysofa0 libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev libnuma-dev
  libobjc4 libomp-7-dev libomp5-7 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi3 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libpentaho-reporting-flow-engine-java libpixie-java
  libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-cipher-java libplexus-classworlds-java libplexus-component-annotations-java libplexus-interpolation-java
  libplexus-io-java libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils2-java libpmix-dev libpmix2 libpq5 libpsm-infinipath1 libpsm2-2
  libpython3-dev libpython3.7 libpython3.7-dev libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libpython3.9-dev libqt5concurrent5 libqt5designer5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5script5 libqt5test5 libqxp-0.0-0 libraw19 librdmacm1 librelaxng-datatype-java libreoffice-base-core librepository-java
  librngom-java libsac-java libsaxonhe-java libsdl1.2debian libserializer-java libservlet-api-java libservlet3.1-java libshiboken2-5.11
  libsisu-inject-java libsisu-plexus-java libslf4j-java libsnappy-java libsnappy-jni libstaroffice-0.0-0 libstax-ex-java libstreambuffer-java
  libtommath1 libtxw2-java libucx0 libunique-1.0-0 libvpx5:i386 libvulkan1 libwagon-http-java libwagon-provider-api-java
  libwebsocket-api-java libwps-0.4-4 libx264-155:i386 libx265-165 libx265-165:i386 libx32asan5 libx32atomic1 libx32gcc-8-dev libx32gcc1
  libx32gomp1 libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0 libx32stdc++6 libx32ubsan1 libxerces2-java libxml-commons-external-java
  libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxml-java libxmlbeans-java libxom-java libxsom-java libxz-java libzmf-0.0-0 linux-image-4.19.0-19-amd64
  llvm-7 llvm-7-dev llvm-7-runtime lp-solve mpi-default-bin mpi-default-dev openmpi-bin openmpi-common python-dbus python-talloc python3-cson
  python3-dev python3-libvoikko python3-numpy python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.sip python3-sip python3-speg python3.7-minimal
  python3.9-dev texlive-lang-english texmaker-data uim-fep uim-xim xfce4-notes
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  blueman coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcoinmp1v5 cpp cpp-10 fcitx-frontend-qt5 firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc firebird3.0-server-core
  firebird3.0-utils g++ g++-10 gcc gcc-10 gfortran gfortran-10 gimp gimp-data gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0 graphviz gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad libann0 libasan6 libavcodec58
  libavcodec58:i386 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavresample4:i386 libavutil56 libavutil56:i386 libbabl-0.1-0 libbrlapi0.8
  libbrotli-dev libbrotli1 libbrotli1:i386 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libc6-i386 libc6-x32
  libcdt5 libcgraph6 libcodec2-0.9 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcrypt-dev libdav1d4 libdav1d4:i386 libdc1394-25 libde265-0 libdouble-conversion3
  libdw1:i386 libegl-mesa0 libfbclient2 libfluidsynth2 libfreetype-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libfreetype6-dev libgarcon-gtk3-1-0
  libgbm1 libgbm1:i386 libgcc-10-dev libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgegl-0.4-0 libgfortran-10-dev libgfortran5 libgimp2.0 libgirepository-1.0-1 libglapi-mesa
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0
  libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgvc6 libgvpr2 libheif1 libib-util libicu67 libilmbase25 libinstpatch-1.0-2
  libjs-jquery-ui liblab-gamut1 libldb2 libllvm11 libllvm11:i386 libltc11 libmd4c0 libmfx1 libmpdec3 libmypaint-1.5-1 libmysofa1 libnm0
  libnsl-dev libnss-nis libnss-nis:i386 libnss-nisplus libnss-nisplus:i386 libopenexr25 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi3 libopenni2-0 libosmesa6
  libosmesa6:i386 libpathplan4 libpmix-dev libpmix2 libpocketsphinx3 libpostproc55 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.9
  libpython3.9-dev libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5designer5 libqt5gui5 libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediagsttools5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5qmlmodels5 libqt5quick5 libqt5script5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5
  libqt5test5 libqt5waylandclient5 libqt5waylandcompositor5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 librabbitmq4 libraw20
  librubberband2 libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsmbclient libsphinxbase3 libsrt1.4-gnutls libstdc++-10-dev libswresample3
  libswresample3:i386 libswscale5 libtirpc-dev libucx0 libunwind8:i386 libvpx6 libvpx6:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libwbclient0 libwebpmux3
  libwebpmux3:i386 libx264-160 libx264-160:i386 libx265-192 libx265-192:i386 libxcb-xinput0 libxfce4panel-2.0-4 libxfce4ui-2-0 libz3-4
  libz3-4:i386 locales network-manager openmpi-bin ppp python3 python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-cups python3-dbus python3-dev
  python3-distutils python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gst-1.0 python3-ldb python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3-numpy python3-pycurl
  python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.sip python3-sip python3-smbc python3-talloc python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-minimal
  qt5-gtk-platformtheme qtwayland5 samba-libs uim uim-anthy uim-data uim-gtk2.0 uim-gtk2.0-immodule uim-gtk3 uim-gtk3-immodule uim-qt5
  uim-qt5-immodule xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-weather-plugin
Suggested packages:
  cpp-doc gcc-10-locales firebird3.0-server firebird3.0-doc g++-multilib g++-10-multilib gcc-10-doc gcc-multilib flex gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-10-multilib gfortran-multilib gfortran-doc gfortran-10-multilib gfortran-10-doc gimp-data-extras gvfs-backends graphviz-doc
  frei0r-plugins glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386 freetype2-doc libgirepository1.0-dev libglib2.0-doc libxml2-utils
  libvisual-0.4-plugins libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-tools:i386 libjs-jquery-ui-docs openmpi-doc
  qt5-image-formats-plugins qt5-qmltooling-plugins libstdc++-10-doc libteam-utils python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python3-apt-dbg
  python-apt-doc python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg python-numpy-doc python3-numpy-dbg python3-pytest libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-doc
  python3-pycurl-dbg python3-pyqt5-dbg python3.9-venv python3.9-doc
Recommended packages:
  libc-devtools gcc-multilib pocketsphinx-en-us uim-xim uim-fep
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  clang clang-7 g++-8 g++-8-multilib g++-multilib gcc-8 gcc-8-multilib gcc-multilib gfortran-8 lib32stdc++-8-dev libboost-all-dev
  libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-mpi-python1.67-dev libboost-mpi-python1.67.0 libclang-7-dev libclang-dev libgcc-8-dev libgfortran-8-dev
  libldb1 libobjc-8-dev libpyside2-5.11 libreoffice libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-calc libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-librelogo libreoffice-math libreoffice-nlpsolver libreoffice-report-builder
  libreoffice-report-builder-bin libreoffice-script-provider-python libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
  libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql libreoffice-voikko libreoffice-writer libstdc++-8-dev libx32stdc++-8-dev python-dbusmock python-gi
  python-pyside2.qtcore python-pyside2.qtgui python-pyside2.qtwidgets python3-uno python3.7 python3.7-dev rstudio texmaker xfce4-notes-plugin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cpp-10 g++-10 gcc-10 gfortran-10 gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-nm-1.0 graphviz libann0 libasan6 libbrlapi0.8 libbrotli-dev
  libbrotli1:i386 libcdt5 libcgraph6 libcodec2-0.9 libcodec2-0.9:i386 libcrypt-dev libdav1d4 libdav1d4:i386 libdc1394-25
  libdouble-conversion3 libdw1:i386 libfluidsynth2 libfreetype-dev libgarcon-gtk3-1-0 libgbm1:i386 libgcc-10-dev libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-dev libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-dev
  libgfortran-10-dev libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgvc6 libgvpr2 libicu67 libilmbase25 libinstpatch-1.0-2 libjs-jquery-ui liblab-gamut1 libldb2
  libllvm11 libllvm11:i386 libltc11 libmd4c0 libmfx1 libmpdec3 libmypaint-1.5-1 libmysofa1 libnsl-dev libnss-nis libnss-nis:i386
  libnss-nisplus libnss-nisplus:i386 libopenexr25 libopenni2-0 libpathplan4 libpmix-dev libpocketsphinx3 libpython3.9 libpython3.9-dev
  libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib libqt5qmlmodels5 librabbitmq4 libraw20 libsphinxbase3 libsrt1.4-gnutls libstdc++-10-dev
  libtirpc-dev libucx0 libunwind8:i386 libvpx6 libvpx6:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libx264-160 libx264-160:i386 libx265-192 libx265-192:i386
  libxcb-xinput0 libz3-4 libz3-4:i386 python3-ldb python3-pyqt5.sip python3-talloc python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-minimal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  blueman coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcoinmp1v5 cpp fcitx-frontend-qt5 firebird3.0-common firebird3.0-common-doc firebird3.0-server-core
  firebird3.0-utils g++ gcc gfortran gimp gimp-data gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad libavcodec58 libavcodec58:i386 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavresample4:i386 libavutil56
  libavutil56:i386 libbabl-0.1-0 libbrotli1 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-x32 libc6-i386
  libc6-x32 libde265-0 libegl-mesa0 libfbclient2 libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libfreetype6-dev libgbm1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgegl-0.4-0 libgfortran5 libgimp2.0
  libgirepository-1.0-1 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin
  libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libheif1 libib-util libnm0 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi3
  libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libpmix2 libpostproc55 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5designer5 libqt5gui5
  libqt5help5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5multimediagsttools5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5
  libqt5positioning5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5script5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5svg5
  libqt5test5 libqt5waylandclient5 libqt5waylandcompositor5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 librubberband2
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 libsmbclient libswresample3 libswresample3:i386 libswscale5 libwbclient0 libwebpmux3 libwebpmux3:i386
  libxfce4panel-2.0-4 libxfce4ui-2-0 locales network-manager openmpi-bin ppp python3 python3-apt python3-brlapi python3-cairo python3-cups
  python3-dbus python3-dev python3-distutils python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-gst-1.0 python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3-numpy
  python3-pycurl python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-sip python3-smbc qt5-gtk-platformtheme qtwayland5 samba-libs uim uim-anthy
  uim-data uim-gtk2.0 uim-gtk2.0-immodule uim-gtk3 uim-gtk3-immodule uim-qt5 uim-qt5-immodule xfce4-panel xfce4-places-plugin
  xfce4-weather-plugin
156 upgraded, 91 newly installed, 52 to remove and 912 not upgraded.
Need to get 318 MB of archives.
After this operation, 635 MB disk space will be freed.
```

*Questions*. 1. Why does it want to remove all those perfectly good packages that I use in my day-to-day life? 2. How can inform apt that I need these programming tools?

*Context*. I am suffering from the problem described [at XFCE4](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=14612)

Comment: I would assume that older versions of the installed packages would be removed after the upgrade so you only have the newer versions.

Comment: @eblock Thanks for your message. But notice it doesn't reinstall clang, for example

Comment: Is there a version of clang available for bullseye from your repositories?

Comment: @eblock If I write sudo apt list | grep clang, I get:: 
...
clang-11-doc/stable,stable 1:11.0.1-2 all
clang-11-examples/stable 1:11.0.1-2 amd64
clang-11-examples/stable 1:11.0.1-2 i386
clang-11/stable 1:11.0.1-2 amd64
clang-11/stable 1:11.0.1-2 i386
clang-7/now 1:7.0.1-8+deb10u2 amd64 [installed,local]
clang-9-doc/stable,stable 1:9.0.1-16.1 all
clang-9-examples/stable 1:9.0.1-16.1 amd64
clang-9-examples/stable 1:9.0.1-16.1 i386
...
and so on

Comment: To see what's causing it, you can just tell it to install the packages it wants to remove in addition to the one you want to upgrade. As this will sooner or later lead to a conflict, you'll get the conflict displayed.

Comment: @A.B You’re saying xfce4-panel isn’t compatible with some of those packages and is the reason apt wants to remove?

Comment: Yes: installing a package doesn't trigger deinstalling other packages unless as a solution to solve a package conflict.

Comment: @A.B my hero king

Comment: And it's probably the other way around: other packages, either obsolete, or provided outside of Debian's official repositories, are not compatible with current xfce4-panel.

Comment: @A.B it seems almost all of those induce a conflict and most of them depend on gcc8-*. (1) Is the right way to do it to uninstall gcc8 and install gcc10? (2) I notice that apt didn't figure that out itself. Perhaps it's the wrong solution?

Comment: I'd use metapackages: gcc, cpp, clang, g++ ... and not a package with a specific version in its name (beside that would be gcc 10 not 9).